# How to assign node and trace colors by a color palette in a sankey diagram?

Tags: r, colors, plotly

I am stuck creating a plotly Sankey diagram, where if I don't set the color, then both source and target nodes are colored by plotly defaults, but if I set the color to a palette (custom or a predefined one), only some of the nodes are colored. I can see that this is probably because the palette only has 11 colors, but only 9 of my nodes are colored? Could anyone tell me why plotly didn't use all 11 colors?
Also if anyone could tell me how I could call the default plotly palette from R it would be wonderful, I would like to create a function to match my tace color with the source color, and I would like to use the default plotly palette to do so but do not know how to call it in R.

```
library("RColorBrewer")

chosen_palette <- brewer.pal(11,"Spectral") #

fig <- plot_ly(
 type = "sankey",
 orientation = "h",
 node = list(
  label = unique(c(dk_cons$Source, dk_cons$Sector)),
  color=chosen_palette,
  pad = 15,
  thickness = 20,
  line = list(
   color = "black",
   width = 0.5
  )
 ),
 link = list(
    source = links$source,
    target = links$target,
    value = links$value
 )
)
fig %>% layout(
 title = "DK Energy Consumption",
 font = list(
  size = 10
 )
)
```

Attached graph[image]

Comment: I'm guessing that it has something to do with the data you're feeding to the diagram as it relates to the color palette. When asking questions it is always a good idea to make your issue reproducible. This includes sample data like the output from `dput()` or `reprex::reprex()`. Check it out: [making R reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269).  If you add a data sample I'm pretty confident I can help you out.